# Error when Initializing the Firebase component in Nativescript

Tags: facebook, firebase, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to setup Firebase in my Nativescript app(Angular 2- TypeScript). However, It prompts me the error as below.
*A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling Facebook.setApplicationId before Initializing the sdk.*

Why should I provide the Facebook app ID for the start-up?

Any idea?

Much appreciate.

Comment: I assume you're using nativescript-plugin-firebase. Did you answer 'yes' when you were asked (during plugin installation) whether or not you're using Facebook login?

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen - I did answer 'Yes'. But, I thought it was just a configuration matter. I have amended the firebase.nativescript.json file, I set the  "facebook_auth": false.

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen - Do I need to re-install and re-generate the Firebase config file?

Comment: If you enabled Facebook then a valid Facebook app id is required. If you don't want it you can adjust the generated 'firebase.nativescript.json' file and reinstall the plugin. Also re-add the iOS platform as the Facebook SDK may be 'hanging' in that folder.

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen- Alright. I will give a try on this. adjusting the generated 'firebase.nativescript.json' and reinstalling the component both are need to be done? By adjusting the 'firebase.nativescript.json' file it won't work?

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen - Thank you. I resolved it by regenerating the json file and reinstall the nativescript-firebase.plugin. But, Now I encountered another issue. When I hit the login button and wired up the Google Authentication type, it has thrown me an error "Google Play Services is required for this features, but not available on this device." , Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved by reinstalling the native-script-firebase-plugin without initialized the Facebook's Authentication for this error message "***A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling Facebook.setApplicationId before Initializing the SDK***"

As for the second error message "***Google Play Service is required on this device***", I just installed and upgraded the Google Play Service on the particular Android Emulator, and it works fine now.

In conclusion, is worth to check the Google Play Service it has been installed and upgraded to the appropriate version or not.